# recursive algorithm on list of numbers , to find out if i have enough steps get to to the end

Tags: python, recursion, logic

If I have a list of numbers  ,

for example [3,4,5,7,0,5,2] .

Every element in the list is represent the number of max steps I can move forward from this cell .
a good list is when I can get to the end of the list  , a bad list is when I don't have enough steps to get to the end of the list .

I try to write the following code but its not right :

```
def recu(li):

    if li[0] == 0:
        print("not working")
        return 'Null'

    if li[0] >= len(li):
        print('finished with success')
        return 'Null'

    if li[0] < len(li):
        print(li[li[0]:])
        return recu(li[li[0]:])




recu(list1)
```

can you please help me ?

Comment: is it leetcode [jump game](https://leetcode.com/problems/jump-game/)?, in your code you need to keep the track of the jump you make and at what position you are present, i think recurrsion is not the right approach to go

Comment: *"I try to write the following code but its not right"* Could you please explain in more detail why you think it's "not right"? What's not right? Does the code produce an error message when run on a specific input list? Does it return the wrong result? Please explain in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic programming for that.

```py
def solution(x):
    a = [False] * len(x)  # list of accessible cells
    a[0] = True  # first cell accessible
    for i, (p, k) in enumerate(zip(a, x)):
        if p:
            for j in range(i, i + k + 1):
                try:
                    a[j] = True  # mark all the cells that can be reached from the processed to the cells
                except IndexError:
                    return True
    return False

print(solution([3,4,5,7,0,5,2]))
```

You also can use recursion:

```py
arr = [3, 4, 5, 7, 0, 5, 2]

def f(i):
    if i + arr[i] >= len(arr):
        print(True)
        exit(0)
    for j in range(i + 1, i + arr[i] + 1):
        f(j)

f(0)
print(False)
```

Comment: care to explain what you have done ?

Comment: Hey , thanks for the answer , but its not recursive .

Comment: Hello! I edited my answer. And wrote solution using recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the logic you are looking for?

```
def is_good(l):
    e = l[0]
    return False if e == 0 else True if e >= len(l) -1 else is_good(l[e:])
```

I tried a few lists - and that makes sense, from my understanding of the problem:

```
is_good([0,1,3])           # Returns False
is_good([3,3,5,0,1])       # Returns False 
is_good([1,7,2,3,0])       # Returns True
is_good([[3,4,5,7,0,5,2])  # Returns True
```

I assume you have to step on or beyond the last element - if you just need to go beyond

```
def is_good(l):
    e = l[0]
    return False if e == 0 else True if e >= len(l) else is_good(l[e:])
```

Comment: "if something then false else true" is a bit convoluted. You could use logical operators instead of an if/else: `return e > 0 and (e >= len(l) or is_good(l[e:]))`

Comment: @Stef I agree with you and it is clear that a lot of those conditions can be often written in a more compact way. On the other hand, I think it reads very clearly, and for some solutions I still prefer to privilege clarity over compactness, especially in a situation like where the existing code is flawed or extremely redundant! I would argue after one lesson of programming you would understand `if else else`, while for the more compact version you propose you need to stop for a sec.

Comment: It must be a matter of taste, then, because I would argue exactly the opposite. I find the python `if else` super hard to read when it is nested; whereas the `and / or` version is extremely logical and intuitive. "and" and "or" are logical English words that I'm used to manipulate when speaking and reading and writing, not just when programming; but using True and False explicitly inside a nested if/else expression doesn't look remotely like an English sentence, and requires quite a mental effort to parse properly (I need to literally draw the expression tree in my head and ponder it)

Comment: Your solution doesn't work. For example `print(is_good([2, 2, 0, 2, 1]))` returns `False` but it is not correct.

Comment: @Ratery doesn't each number represent the # of steps forward you can take? l[0] = 2, you get to l[2] which is 0, hence you are stuck there, no?

Comment: @nikeros "Every element in the list is represent the number of **max** steps I can move forward from this cell"

Comment: So, you can move forward 1 cell.

Comment: @Ratery oh I see - thank you for highlighting that. Let me check. That is actually a more interesting problem

Answer (score 0):

I can offer the solution of your problem, using the algorithm **Depth first search**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
const int maximumSize=40;
vector<int> visited(maximumSize, 0);
void dfs(int current, int previous, vector<int>& input)
{
    if(visited[current]==1)
    {
        return;
    }
    if(current>=(input.size()-1))
    {
        cout<<"finished with success"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    if((input[current]==0) && (current<(input.size()-1)))
    {
        cout<<"not working"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    visited[current]=1;
    int newCurrent=(current+input[current]);
    for(int next=newCurrent; next<=newCurrent; ++next)
    {
        if(next==previous)
        {
            continue;
        }
        dfs(next, current, input);
    }
    return;
}
void solve()
{
    vector<int> inputVector={3, 4, 5, 7, 0, 5, 2};
    dfs(0, -1, inputVector);
    return;
}
int main()
{
    solve();
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
{3, 4, 5, 7, 0, 5, 2}
```

Here is the result:

```
finished with success
```

Input:

```
{3, 4, 5, 0, 7, 0, 5}
```

Here is the result:

```
not working
```